# Spring Rest Service @RequestParam required = true only if another @RequestParam is present

Tags: java, spring, rest, validation

I have the following code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void test(@RequestParam(required= false) String fromDate,
                 @RequestParam(required= false) String toDate) {
}
```

The "rules" are:

- if fromDate and toDate are empty --> OK
- if fromDate has a value and toDate is empty --> OK
- if fromDate and toDate have value --> OK
- if fromDate is empty and toDate has a value --> NOT OK

It is possible to do that with custom Spring validations?

Something like...

```
@RequestParam(required = false)
@ValidateDependingOnAnotherField(field = "fromDate") String toDate
```

Thanks!

Comment: This isn't supported inherently, unless you declare three controller methods (and leave `toDate` optional if there's no `fromDate`). It seems simpler to do the check yourself and throw an exception.

Comment: Thanks for your answers @chrylis. That was my first thought, but, if I am not wrong, the entry point will always be the one with both optional parameters.

Comment: If you are okay.. you can write down your custom annotation where you can pass on your method parameters to the aspect and do your validations. But this approach is different from what you have asked for.

Comment: You can include the `param` as part of the mapping, but that's just too much trouble.

Comment: @chrylis yeap, that's too much trouble :S

Comment: @asg actually I think that's what I want!